# Trying to compile phpredis on a mac using phpize54

Tags: php, php5, mac-osx-server, mac, redis

I installed php 5.4 using mac port.  I then git cloned the phpredis repository ( https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis ).

Then, I execute these commands:

```
phpize54
./configure
make && make install
```

The problem is that thge library gets compiled with php 5.3 and installed in this directory: `/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/`

I would need it to be compiled using php 5.4 and installed in this directory: `/opt/local/lib/php54/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/`

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance guys!

EDIT:

Also, when I write `make test`, I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: redis: 
Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
```